# Identify users with incorrect password policy settings on their profile

Tags: reporting, query

Is it possible to query for the users whose profiles do not have the correct password policy settings?

I was trying to first query on the profile for the password policy settings, but I'm only seeing the `PermissionsPasswordNeverExpires` field on the profile, but that field is just a Boolean field. I'm trying to identify the users whose profiles either do not have password policies set or have the incorrect password policy values. Is there a report I could run to obtain the information? Or, some other option? Or, am I stuck with manually going thru the profiles and identifying the users with incorrect password policy settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware of, you cannot get those values using standard reports.

But the [ProfilePasswordPolicy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profilepasswordpolicy.htm) Metadata API is exactly what you need here, which provides you all the information as required.

> Represents a profile’s password policies. Profile password policies override org-wide password policies for that profile’s users. Use ProfilePasswordPolicy to retrieve password policies for a given profile.